# Simple If Else C# Statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
    private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
    {
        Wrapper cam = new Wrapper();

        //show the image in the EmguCV ImageBox
        WebcamPictureBox.Image = cam.start_cam(capture).Resize(390, 243, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC).ToBitmap();
        FaceDetectedLabel.Text = "Faces Detected : " + cam.facesdetected.ToString();
    }
```

I am working on a C# windows application. I am stuck with a simple question:

How can i do a if else with the condition: If "**cam.facesdetected.ToString()**" if equal or more than 2 do sth, else do nothing.

I tried this, but it does not seems to work. Can anyone help me?

```
        cam.facesdetected = abc;
        MessageBox.Show("The detected faces is:" + abc);

        if (abc >= 2)
        {
            //Do action 
        }

        else
        {
            //Do nothing
        }
```

Comment: What does "but it does not seems to work" mean?  What is the error?

Comment: Would it be `abc = cam.facesdetected;`

Comment: I have declare it as: private int abc;

Comment: It looks like you want to parse the string "2" into an integer, is that correct?

Comment: It means that the return value is "0" for abc when messagebox is pop up but however, cam.facedeteced actual value is "1" cause its a webcame face detection return value

Answer (score 2):

You could:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(abc) > 2)
   DoWork()
```

Although it would probably be wise to declare ABC as an integer to begin with, if it is always an integer.

Comment: Considering that the string appears to come from user provided input `int.TryParse` should probably be used instead.

Comment: I was just thinking the same thing.

Comment: Agreed. The details of the question were a bit.. vague.. so i generalized the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you've got your if statement backwards.

```
abc = cam.facesdetected;
```

Now you can operate on `abc`, as you had listed.

Answer (score 0):

you can only assign leftside variable by rightside variable

```
LHS=RHS
```

you have wrongly assigned
it must be `abc = cam.facesdetected;`

and you can check whether it is greater than & equal to 2 by using `TryParse` Method

```
   bool result = Int32.TryParse(abc, out number);
      if (result)
      {
         if(number>=2)
        {
          //dowork;   
         }   
      }
```

Comment: I believe your syntax to call TryParse is incorrect. See here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use it without assigning any new variable. There is no need to use the `abc` variable. You can use `cam.facesdetected` directly (I suppose that it is a number) like this:

```
    MessageBox.Show("The detected faces is:" + cam.facesdetected.ToString());

    if (cam.facesdetected >= 2)
    {
        //Do action 
    }

    else
    {
        //Do nothing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dont use `.ToString()` when you use numbers.

You are assigning the variable in a wrong way, this should be

```
var abc = cam.facesdetected;
```

if cam.facesdetected is not a number then use

```
var abc = Convert.ToInt32(cam.facesdetected);
```

and then

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(abc) >= 2)
{
   //Do action 
}
```